# How can I export an RDF graph in RDF/XML format?

Tags: xml, graph, rdf, virtuoso

I want to export into a file a graph stored in Virtuoso Open Source. I would need this to be done in both XML and json-ld formats.

For example, given the following graph

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix pes: <http://example.com/resource/> .
pes:mrlHst-5 a pes:MrlHst ;
pes:mrlHstId 5 ;
pes:mrlApplicationDate 2008-09-01 ;
pes:mrlValue 0.01 .
```

I want it to be exported both in RDF/XML format

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:pest="http://example.com/resource"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdf:Description xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               rdf:about="mrlHst-5">
    <pest:mrlHstId>5</pest:mrlHstId>
    <pest:mrlValue>0.01</pest:mrlValue>
    <pest:mrlApplicationDate rdf:datatype="xs:date">2008-09-01</pest:mrlApplicationDate>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="MrlHst"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and in Json-ld format

```
{ "@graph" : [ 
  {
    "@id" : "pes:mrlHst-5",
    "@type" : "pes:MrlHst",
    "mrlHstId" : "5",
    "mrlValue" : "0.01",
    "mrlApplicationDate" : {
      "@type" : "xs:date",
      "@value" : "2008-09-01"},
  ] ,
  "@context" : {
    "rdfs" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "mrlValue" : "http://example.com/resource/mrlValue",
    "rdf" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "mrlApplicationDate" : {
      "@id" : "http://example.com/resource/mrlApplicationDate",
      "@type" : "xs:date"},
    "pes" : "http://example.com/resource",
    "mrlHstId" : "http://example.com/resource/mrlHstId"
  }
}
```

I haven't found any feature able to export a graph in these formats. 
In my case the graph has been generated in Virtuoso using the R2RML mapping over a set of local DB tables.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. I don't understand what you mean by "the ontology of a generic graph." Perhaps what you need is to [dump a graph](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFDatasetDump)? That only delivers Turtle, but there are many ways (with Virtuoso and otherwise) to transform Turtle to RDF/XML or JSON-LD...

Comment: I have re-edited the question, hopefully in a more clear way.

Comment: I have reformulated the question, since the reference to the ontology was misleading

Comment: Re-reading since the new edits…  Is your desire explicitly to *export* (so, to execute a command within Virtuoso that results in a file being written somewhere) or more generally to *extract* (so, to execute a command elsewhere, that results in a file being acquired)?  The latter is doable with something like `curl` passing a SPARQL query with an HTTP `Accept:` request header specifying your desired serialization.  More details will go into an answer, if that's suitable for your needs.

Comment: @ TailTed The general solution is in my case preferable because it can be executed, for example, from a Python process.